# Numbering SQL query results based on groupings

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table containing many rows of data, each of which is assigned a section, consisting of one letter and one digit (e.g. A.1). I have a requirement to retrieve all of the data from this table and order it by this sectioning. When pulling this data I have been instructed to generate a new column numbering each row within this section thus creating subsections (e.g. A.1.1, A.1.2)

Given a group of data with "sections" for example a table with 2 sections A.1, B.1 I want to be able to number each of these results in an additional column "SubNumber" 1, 2, 3 etc. When the row is a new section this numbering has to restart.

Meaning a table result set like below:

```
Data    | Section | SubNumber
_______________________
record1 | A.1     | 1
record2 | A.1     | 2
record3 | A.1     | 3
record4 | B.1     | 1
record5 | B.1     | 2
```

I've been trying in SQL to create this SubNumber on the fly and have not came close.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What determines the sequence?

Comment: the sequence is determined using an order by of Section, Sequence and LibraryOpNumber. These are 3 columns from the table I am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using variables:

```
  select t.*,
         (@rn := if(@s = Section, @rn + 1,
                    if(@s := Section, 1, 1)
                   )
         ) as SubNumber
  from table t cross join
       (select @rn := 0, @s := '') vars
  order by Section;
```

The issue here is that the numbering is *arbitrary* within a group.  You need to have some way of specifying the numbers.  When you decide on that, then add that column to the `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a user variable to add the sequence number is possible, but a common issue is the order that the data is in when the sequence number is applied (rather than when the query finishes). Solution to this is to get the data in a sub query with an order by clause, then add the sequence number after that.

```
SELECT sub0.Data, sub0.Section, @seq = if(Section = @section, @seq + 1, if (@Section := section, 1, 1))
(
    SELECT Data, Section
    FROM sometable
    ORDER BY Section, Sequence, LibraryOpNumber
) sub0
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT @section:='', @seq:=0
) sub1
```